# How to get return type of interface<T>?

Tags: java, interface, stack

im stuck in this problem i tried to correct it but nothing changed..

so first of all "Stack" is an interface 
[and this is the required method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koWVi.png)

which copy the array stack and return it as new stack, this my code:

```
public class ArrayStack<Type> implements Stack<Type> {

private int maxSize;
private int top;
private Type [] nodes;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

public ArrayStack(int n){
    maxSize = n ;
    top = -1 ;
    nodes = (Type[]) new Object[n];
}



@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

public Stack<Type> copy() {

    int n = nodes.length;
    Type[] ns = (Type[]) new Object[n];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){

        ns[i]= nodes[i];
    }



    return ns;
}
```

so i get a compile error on "**return ns;**" statement which says:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Type[] to Stack

i don't know if i wrote the method signature or the new array in a wrong way ..

i will appreciate your help :)

Comment: Well yea, the problem is exactly like error describes - you are trying to return a array of Type rather than expected Stack object. You need to wrap this array into a Stack object to match expected method output type.

Comment: You need to return a `Stack`, but you return an array and for some reason you expect that to work. Why? And if you want to `copy` the stack, why do you copy the data from the source stack to an array and not to a new `Stack`?

Comment: An array is not a `Stack` - this is the whole reason `ArrayStack` exists

Comment: Hint: dont use generic parameter names like `Type` . Stay with the convention, and just use T. You have to understand that `Type` isn't really a "class name". Such things can lead to confusion quickly, so dont do that!

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
Type[] ns
```

is returned, and should thus be:

```
Stack<Type>
```

But an array of T's ... isnt a Stack of T. You have to make up your mind, should the method return an array (then change the signature), or should it return a new Stack instance (in that case, you can't return that `ns` array!)

As the name `copy()` implies the later, you probably should:

- create a new instance of ArrayStack
- setup the stack of that new Stack with the same content that the original Stack offers ... and then
- return that new ArrayStack instance.

Comment: Extending your answer: since the method is named `copy()` he'd probably want to return `ArrayStack<Type>`, i.e. create a new array stack from `ns` and return that.